# Javascript syntax error warning assigning ViewData

Tags: javascript

This is a softball for somebody I'm sure.  I'm cleaning up some code that I inherited and have this situation.

Controller page

```
DataTable dtYearTable = new DataTable();
dtYearTable.Columns.Add("text");
dtYearTable.Columns.Add("value");
dtYearTable.Rows.Add("2014", "2014");
dtYearTable.Rows.Add("2013", "2013");
dtYearTable.Rows.Add("2012", "2012");
ViewData["dtyears"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtYearTable);
```

Aspx page

```
var _programs = <% = ViewData["dtyears"] %>;
```

So at the end of the code line for the aspx page, I get the little red squiggly saying syntax error.  The code runs and works fine, I'd just like to know how to remove the red, syntax error warning.

Thanks!

Comment: Curious as to why this would get downvoted.  Any takers?  This was just an honest question concerning my confusion on why the IDE behaving this way and if there is a way to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

the aspx part should be `<%= ... %>` with no space between `%` and `=`